Intercept API calls in Cypress - Should I keep the wait separately?
With the cypress code snippet given below, I visit a homepage and then click on a profile button which shows the profile in the side of the home page (not in a separate page). Is it ok to wait like this or are there serious problems in my approach ?
//Some code to intercept an api with alias getProfile. 
MyHomePage.clickProfileButton();
ProfileStubUtil.waitForGetProfileApi();
//test stuff.

  waitForGetProfileApi(): Cypress.Chainable<Interception> {
    const wait = cy.wait("@getProfile");
    return wait;
  }

I heard that we could chain the wait off the action which needs to wait i.e.
MyHomePage.clickProfileButton(). So, that would become something like  MyHomePage.clickProfileButton().wait("@getProfile");. Is this any better than what I have done if yes/no, then why?

IMO it's not a problem as long as

you are not using the return value of waitForGetProfileApi (in which case don't do the return)
or are using it right away and not performing other steps before checking the interception (the return value is the command chain)
nobody else has to work with the test code and you always remember what you wrote in the PO (which works against one of the benefits of PO, implementation hiding).

There's a reason why Cypress docs say

You cannot assign or work with the return values of any Cypress command. Commands are enqueued and run asynchronously.


If you are asking about chaining off the .click(), Cypress says

It is unsafe to chain further commands that rely on the subject after .click()

which I take to mean the subject can become stale after the click, since click (usually) does something to alter the page.
Technically .wait() is a parent command, so chaining it off something does nothing useful (it ignores the subject passed from the chain).
